# Node.js for a backbone.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I will be making an javascript application using either backbonejs or canjs for the frontend and need a server-side language to connect to the database. Would node.js work fine for this?

I cant find any docs on someone trying to use node.js as the backend...

really not trying to use php, rails, asp, etc...

Examples/explanations would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a set of links to resources that I've found quite useful.

[Basic Node.js and Backbone application](http://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/basic-node-js-and-backbone-js-application-ii/)

[Todos MVC with Backbone, Node.js and MongoDB](http://jamesor.com/2012/04/todosmvc-backbone-nodejs-mongodb/)

[Reusing Backhonejs models on server side with Node](http://andyet.net/blog/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: These are some great resources. If you choose to use socket.io with your backbone for real time updates, this library has worked great for me: https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely use node.js for this

Check out [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) for a simple API to deal with your requests. They have some great docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. You could also check out http://www.nodebeginner.org.